# What is deploying a server?

Tags: sql-server, deployment

I have the server.. 
My colleagues have talked about deploying a server. I am a new in computer world I don't understand what they mean. Could you explain me please what is deploying the server?

Best regards,
Ragims

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a Network Specialist, typical tasks I'd expect involved in "deploying" a new server would be:

1. Buy server
2. Install OS
3. Install applications
4. Configure network settings (IP address, default gateway, etc)
5. Patch the server into the LAN switch
6. Configure appropriate firewall rules to allow required access to the server.
7. Add server into monitoring and management platforms

I'm sure people on here can recommend a lot more items for the list...

Answer (score 1):

You can think of is as a synonym to "**install**".

To deploy a software on a server is installing the software on the server.
To deploy a server might be either the above or actually unpacking the server box and mount the server in a rack and then installing an OS.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying a server can mean different things, but typically it means to put into production providing services as needed, or made available for use.  (a.k.a. 'read to go' 'ready for production' 'serving applications')

Answer (score 0):

Deploying to the server basically means copying a file or set of files to another machine or to another folder, depending if the server is running local or at another machine.
It's that simple.
More context would be needed to provide you with a better answer.